# How to enable Object Browser Search in Visual Studio 2010 Possessional

Tags: visual-studio-2010, objectbrowser

I'm using VS2010 and can't seem to find how to enable the search bar in the Object Browser.

I've searched for quite some time and all I've been able to find are instructions on how to enable it in VS2010 Express. Namely to enable expert mode via Tools > Settings > Expert Settings. These settings however appear not to exist in my version.

Has anyone else had the same issue?

Thanks 
Glen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't quite explain it and it's not very helpful for anyone else having the same issue, but it seems that the issue is now resolved.

I suspect it was resolved with a VS Windows Update.

Answer (score 2):

In VS 2010 I added the object browser using Tools > Settings > Expert Settings.  I did not get the search box when I picked the object browser from the VIEW menu.  I then closed VS 2010 and restarted it.  The search feature then appeared on the object browser.